# Is the use of 'not' for contrast a case of ellipsis?

Tags: ellipsis

> The car was red, **not blue**.
>
> I went home, **not to the supermarket**.

In these two examples, which use the word 'not' to create contrast, are we seeing a case of ellipsis? Could we find the original forms of these sentences by adding the missing components that would make it grammatical? (See below.)

> The car was red, **and it was** not blue.
>
> I went home, **and I did** not **go** to the supermarket.

I think that this explains what is happening here, as the extra words are superfluous.

Comment: This question is better suited for [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com) as it's for learning *about* English, rather than learning English as a language learner. I'd migrate the question to that site for you, but it has a bounty so I cannot.

Comment: I'd consider *not blue* / *not to the supermarket* appositives (an appositive adjective in the first case, I think an appositive adverb clause in the second?) and wouldn't call them ellipses any more than any other appositive structures (eg. I wouldn't consider *I live in Canada, the land of the free* an ellipsis of *I live in Canada and Canada is the land of the free*). Also cf. *I went home, to my mother* not being equivalent to *I went home and I went to my mother*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commas are often used in English to replace elided elements. (This has nothing to do with "not". A famous example: ["To err is human; to forgive, divine."](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/to-err-is-human.html) The comma replaces "is".) In this case, I'd read each comma as replacing "and":

> The car was red and not blue.

> I went home and not to the supermarket.

There may be other options; for example, the commas in these sentences could replace "but" in certain contexts.